# Ember: Using this.get('controller.').content, find methods

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using  this.get('controller.raceModal').content, I am trying to achieve is this;

If I dig into the following expression

```
this.get('controller.raceModal').content.content
```

I find an array with a bunch of objects, I am trying to see if one of the methods in content will allow me to do a find. The objects have an attribute 'id' which I would like to do a find on something like:

```
this.get('controller.raceModal').content.find({'id', '15'})
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say where you are trying to do this (controller, route) but if it is truely an array you should be able to do this:

```
this.get('controller.raceModal').findBy('id', '15')
```

Comment: cool. 'content' should atleast be moved into the 'controller.raceModal' part. Secondly, 'content' shouldn't have to be accessed directly. Done right, content is the model over the controller and all properties on content are aliased directly on the controller.